# Python program which finds specific terms entered by a user in multiple HTML Files

Tags: python, html

A program (python for example) has been design that highlights which html file contains the search term, which has been entered by the user.

I need help writing a python program which finds terms in multiple HTML files that I have made myself, and the program also states the amount of times the term appears in the HTML file. The term can be entered by the user.

I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: If the html files are hosted, look into the requests module. If the files are local, look into file reading. When you have the file contents as a string, you can use htmlsource.count(searchstring)

Comment: In addition to Sri's comment, take a look at [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse HTML using Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML files are stored locally:

```py
word = input('Word to search for: ')

html_files = ['first.html', 'second.html']

for i in html_files:
    with open(i, 'r') as f:
        matches = {index: x.strip() for index, x in enumerate(f.readlines()) if word in x}:

        print('Found {} matches on {}:'.format(len(matches), i))

        for n, line in matches.items():
            print('Line {}: {}'.format(n, line))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you explain the variable "matches"? Thank you

Comment: Sure. It uses [List Comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) It means:  "Create a dictionary. Each dictionary entry will have 'index', which is the current line number, as key and the line content itself as value, but only create the dictionary entry if you find the word inside the line.". The `strip()` function just deletes blank spaces, and the `enumerate()` allows us to refer `index` by yielding `line_number, line_content` on each `for` iteration. See docs [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Comment: Would appreciate if you could validate the answer ^^ @nicotividad